# I want to read a .txt file seperated by spaces, line by line and store it in a hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, text-files

I used the following code:

```
print "Enter the log file name \n";
chomp (my $log_file = <STDIN>);
my %log_hash ;
open(my $log, "<$log_file") or die "Can't open file";
while ( my $log_line = <$log> ) {
    chomp($log_line);
    my($log_key,$log_val) = split(" ", $log_line,2);
    print $log_key , "\n";
    print $log_val , "\n";
    $log_hash{$log_key} = $log_val;
    print $log_hash{$log_key};

}
```

When I run this, I see that only the last line is being printed. The rest of the values are not present in `log_hash`.
How do I rectify this?

I tried this code, and still have the same problem.
Log file:

```
instance_73 434 641
instance_83 428 635
instance_56 434 640...
```

I used the code to open a command file as well.
cmd file:

```
CMD_1 447 632
CMD_2 449 643
CMD_3 434 632...
```

There is no problem with this. The command file gives the expected result(the keys and values are interchanged), but the for the log file, only the last line is getting stored.

This is the result for the log file:

```
...instance_91
446 631
instance_61
442 631
instance_40
448 647
448 647
```

This is for the command file:

```
447 632
CMD_1
CMD_1
449 643
CMD_2
CMD_2
434 632
CMD_3
CMD_3...
```

Comment: Show the sample input please.

Comment: To inspect how a data structure actually looks like, use something like the  `Data::Dumper` module. Could you edit the question to show such output?  Likely, your hash is OK but the lines contain an extra `\r` character or so that causes the same output line to be overwritten.

Comment: Your code is working for me. :)

Comment: Add NEW-LINE character to your print lines to be sure you do not misread the output: `print($log_hash{$log_key},"\n");`

Comment: Hi, I tried this code, and still have the same problem.
Log file: 
instance_73 434 641
instance_83 428 635
instance_56 434 640

I used the code to open a command file as well. 
cmd file:
CMD_1 447 632
CMD_2 449 643
CMD_3 434 632

There is no problem with this. The command file gives the expected result, but the for the log file, only the last line is getting stored.

Answer (score 1):

Without some sample input, it's very hard to tell. However the most likely cause is that hashes require unique keys, and maybe your logfile isn't delivering those.

Consider a log:

```
today some message
today another message
today some more messages
```

These will all be inserted into hash element `today` and each will overwrite each other.

To check if this is what's happening:

```
push (  @{$log_hash{$log_key}, $log_val );
```

And then use `Data::Dumper` to view:

```
print Dumper \%log_hash;
```

Comment: My log file has unique values.
Hi, I tried this code, and still have the same problem.
Log file: 
instance_73 434 641
instance_83 428 635
instance_56 434 640

I used the code to open a command file as well. 
cmd file:
CMD_1 447 632
CMD_2 449 643
CMD_3 434 632

There is no problem with this. The command file gives the expected result, but the for the log file, only the last line is getting stored.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, I just changed style. Just check this below code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter the log file name: ";
chomp (my $log_file = <STDIN>);
my %log_hash;
open my $log, "<", "$log_file" or die "Can't open file: $!";
while ( my $log_line = <$log> )
{
    chomp $log_line;
    my($log_key, $log_val) = split(" ", $log_line, 2);
    print $log_key, "\n";
    print $log_val, "\n";
    $log_hash{$log_key} = $log_val;
    print $log_hash{$log_key}, "\n";
}
close $log;
```

Considering the input data you have written in question.

logfile Output:

```
instance_73
434 641
434 641
instance_83
428 635
428 635
instance_56
434 640
434 640
```

cmdfile Output:

```
CMD_1
447 632
447 632
CMD_2
449 643
449 643
CMD_3
434 632
434 632
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code to open Two files. The log file is still giving me the same problem, but it works just fine for the command file. the log file looks like this: instance_73 434 641
instance_83 428 635
instance_56 434 640
instance_29 435 619
instance_53 442 647
instance_44 442 650

Comment: @shreyaturmari: With the given input data of logfile, this code will give you following output: `instance_73
434 641
434 641
instance_83
428 635
428 635
instance_56
434 640
434 640`
If this is not correct please add your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @lines = <DATA>;
foreach (@lines){
    chomp $_;
    my ($key, $val) = split (" ", $_, 2);
    print "$key:$val\n";
}
__DATA__
this is line number 1
this is line number 2
```

Comment: This really needs more explanation as to what it's doing.